# NSUserDefaults not getting stored string value

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, nsstring, uitextview, nsuserdefaults

I have `UIWebView` for reading content. After that i select some text from content stores in string using `NSUserDefaults` in Viewcontroller. Then i retrieve this string value and displays in `UITextView` to  viewcontroller1. But the `UITextView` is not updating text from viewcontroller. The `NSUserDefaults` also not getting updating text. Im using `[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller1 animated:YES];` for switch to viewcontroller1.

viewcontroller:

```
[wbCont loadHTMLString:webString baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:wbCont];

    NSMutableArray *items = [[[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] menuItems] mutableCopy];
    if (!items) items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIMenuItem *menuItem;
    menuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"BookMark" action:@selector(save:)];
    [items addObject:menuItem];
    [menuItem release];
    menuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Note" action:@selector(note:)];
    [items addObject:menuItem];
    [menuItem release];

    [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems:items];
    [items release];


- (BOOL) canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(save:))
    {
        return YES;



    }
    else if (action == @selector(note:))
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else if (action == @selector(copy:))
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}


    -(void)save:(id)sender{
        NSString   *selection = [wbCont stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"];

        NSLog(@"selection is %@",selection);

         NSUserDefaults *userData1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
            [userData1 setObject:selection forKey:@"preferenceName"];

            [userData1 synchronize];

           [self.navigationController pushViewController:note animated:YES];

    }
```

viewcontroller1:

```
textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,400)];
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    // getting an NSString
    NSString *savedValue = [prefs stringForKey:@"preferenceName"];
NSLog(@"saved is %@", savedValue);
textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", savedValue];
```

Comment: What are you getting in log ? Also there is no need to use `stringWithFormat:` when it is already a string.

Comment: In VC1 `NSLog(@"saved is %@", savedValue);` here

Comment: check my edited question. When i click save it goes to VC1 and displays the savedValue. In VC1 i have automatic back in Navigation bar, when i click the button it goes to VC. Then i select some text go to VC1 it's not working. First time only it's working. second time it's not working

Comment: You didn't tell that what log is printing second time ?

Comment: NSString *savedValue = [prefs objectForKey:@"preferenceName"];
 have you tried this?

Comment: @TheTiger: The problem is in VC1 NSUserDefaults not getting saved string value

Comment: @TheTiget: The second time the log is not printing

Comment: @Bhavik kama: It's not working..

Comment: Inside viewcontroller the UITextView text is updating. But when i switch to VC1 it's not updating.

Comment: as you saying that first time its working and second time its not working..your code is normal.. unless you just see with putting breakpoints and trace each point that what happen in second time.then let us know

Comment: How can i put breakpoint? second time means i didn't reinstall app, i come back VC and switch to VC1 it's not working. If i set breakpoint it affect first time install

Comment: Because of Navigationcontroller and back button cause problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allocation of textView is in `viewDidLoad`.

Updating of textView is in `viewWillAppear`.

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    // getting an NSString
    NSString *savedValue = [prefs stringForKey:@"preferenceName"];
    NSLog(@"saved is %@", savedValue);
    textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", savedValue];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Got it. Can you change your code to  -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{   }

Answer (score 0):

I was checked your code just change `NSSTring` to `NSString` like below it will working.

```
-(void)save:(id)sender{
//    NSSTring   *selection = [wbCont stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"];

    NSString   *selection = [wbCont stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"];
    NSLog(@"selection is %@",selection);

     NSUserDefaults *userData1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
        [userData1 setObject:selection forKey:@"preferenceName"];

        [userData1 synchronize];

       [self.navigationController pushViewController:note animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: then this was worked.. even i checked...selection string is not getting empty right ?

Comment: Maybe the problem is in pushviewcontroller? When i switch to VC1 the back button having, after clicking back button i come to VC then the new text is not updating

Comment: from where you call -(void)save:(id)sender, after editing text view ?

Comment: Please put your entire code here, code for VC and VC1 may be I will do something for you.