# UITableViewCell returns null using objectForKey

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I have textview in VC. Saving this textview using nsuserdefaults and get it later. In VC1 im getting saved textview and displaying in UITableView. But when i launch the app it automcatically displays "null" text in index 0.

VC:

```
-(void)save:(id)sender{

   NSUserDefaults *userData1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userData1 setObject:textView.text forKey:@"savetext"];
    [userData1 synchronize];
}
```

VC1:

```
 -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


textArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    txt=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    // getting an NSString

    NSString *savedValue = [prefs stringForKey:@"savetext"];

    txt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", savedValue];

    MyAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


   // [MyAppDelegate.textArray addObject:txt.text];

       if(![MyAppDelegate.textArray containsObject:txt.text]){
        [MyAppDelegate.textArray addObject:txt.text];


           NSUserDefaults *userData1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
           [userData1 setObject:MyAppDelegate.textArray forKey:@"save"];
           [userData1 synchronize];

    }



    [self.view addSubview:txt];

    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)                                           style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    NSLog(@"Scrolling");

    tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

    //  tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0,300, 0); //values passed are - top, left, bottom, right
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    [tableView reloadData];

    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0,300, 0);


    //self.view = tableView;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];


        }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


        NSMutableArray* myMutableArrayAgain = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"save"]];

        NSLog(@"count is %@",myMutableArrayAgain);


        return [myMutableArrayAgain count];


    }




    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


        NSMutableArray* myMutableArrayAgain = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"save"]];


        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];

        NSLog(@"cell is %@",cell);

        if (cell == nil) {

            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

             NSLog(@"cell is %@",cell);


        }

        // Configure the cell...


        cell.textLabel.text = [myMutableArrayAgain objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:14]];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        return cell;

    }
```

Comment: show the code where you save the text in NSUserdefault.

Comment: may be table reload cause error?

Comment: this is may be due to you save empty text check my code i give condition when save text. delete app and try run again and check.

Comment: Im reinitializing this NSMutableArray* myMutableArrayAgain = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"save"]]; But memeber variable is not working for this

Comment: yeah dont initialise it again and again initialise in viewwilappear and use that in whole file.

Comment: First thing you should never initialized your view's object in viewWillAppear, do it in viewDidLoad instead.

Comment: @Nuzhat actually it every time add value in that array so it needs updated array every time. thats why it need to be in ViewwillAppear.

Comment: @pratikbhiyani: You are correct. I need to update everytime..

Comment: @user2807197: be specific what you want, you are asking same related question to http://stackoverflow.com/q/19217085/1597744 this,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240903/uitableviewcell-returns-null-using-objectforkey,http://stackoverflow.com/q/19240903/1597744,, http://stackoverflow.com/q/19194569/1597744.

Comment: @Virussmca yeah you are right but he is new so it takes time him to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. NSUserDefaults can't process with mutable objects.
Try to store your string into CoreData. Is it simple and powerful. I make it and it works perfect. 
If you have not skills with CoreData here is tutorial:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StMBHzA7h18

Step1 create new file - Data model
Step2 create Entity (name) there add one atribute (name2)
So simple!